# Return factory data to controller always undefined

Tags: angularjs

Trying to return data from the factory and logging within the factory outputs the correct data, but once passed to the controller it is always undefined. If I have my factory logic inside the controller it will work fine. So it must be something simple Im missing here?

**Application**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('animalController', ['$log', '$scope', 'animalResource', function($log, $scope, animalResource) {
        $scope.list = function() {
            $scope.list = 'List Animals';
            $scope.animals = animalResource.get(); // returns undefined data
            $log.info($scope.animals);
        };
        $scope.show = function() {};
        $scope.create = function() {};
        $scope.update = function() {};
        $scope.destroy = function() {};
    }]);

    app.factory('animalResource', ['$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {
        return {
            get: function() {
                $http({method: 'GET', url: '/clusters/xhrGetAnimals'}).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        //$log.info(data, status, headers, config); // return correct data
                        return data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $log.info(data, status, headers, config);
                    });
            },
            post: function() {},
            put: function() {},
            delete: function() {}
        };
    }]);
```

**Log Info**

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    200 function (name) {
        if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

        if (name) {
            return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
        }

        return headersObj;
    } Object {method: "GET", url: "/clusters/xhrGetAnimals"}
```

Comment: `return data;` within success callback doesn't return anything from the `get` function.. try `return $http({method...`. Go through tutorial on angular docs site

Comment: ok you are right, added a return before the $http. make it an answer and Ill accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `get()` method in service is not returning anything. The `return` inside the `success` callback only returns from that particular function.

return the `$http` object

Answer (score 0):

Che this example that is how you use the promises and you return the factory then you access the methods injecting the service on your controller 
Use dot syntax to access the function you define on the service

```
'use strict';
        var app;

        app = angular.module('app.formCreator.services', []);

        app.factory('formCreatorService', [
          '$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
            var apiCall, bjectArrarContainer, deferred, factory, webBaseUrl, _getFormElementsData;
            factory = {};
            deferred = $q.defer();
            bjectArrarContainer = [];
            webBaseUrl = 'https://tools.XXXX_url_XXXXX.com/XXXXXXX/';
            apiCall = 'api/XXXXX_url_XXXX/1000';
            _getFormElementsData = function() {
              $http.get(webBaseUrl + apiCall).success(function(formElements) {
                deferred.resolve(formElements);
              }).error(function(err) {
                deferred.reject(error);
              });
              return deferred.promise;
            };
            factory.getFormElementsData = _getFormElementsData;
            return factory;
          }
        ]);
```

then do it like this for example

```
 'use strict';
            var app;

            app = angular.module('app.formCreator.ctrls', []);

            app.controller('formCreatorController', [
              'formCreatorService', '$scope', function(formCreatorService, $scope) {
                $scope.formElementsData = {};
                formCreatorService.getFormElementsData().then(function(response) {
                  return $scope.formElementsData = response;
                });
              }
            ]);
```